# Exponent Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native, google-api, expo

I want to implement Google Maps in my Exponent app. Everything is OK on development mode but when I build android version of the application the map is empty [image: The empty Google Map on the apk]

I followed all the steps in the [Exponent Docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v12.0.0/sdk/map-view.html) but it doesn't work. How I can fix this problem?

Comment: Anything in the Logs? See: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v12.0.0/guides/logging.html

Comment: @MorrisonChang **Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.** Thanks a lot! I fixed the problem when adding the new cert_fingerprint..